# Should '*.deps.json' file be distributed along with the assembly or inside nuget packages?

Tags: .net-core, nuget-package

Should `*.deps.json` files be distributed along with the assembly or inside the nuget packages?

Comment: An out-of-the-box csproj project, when built and packaged, does not include the deps.json files, if that helps...

Answer (score 9):

You typically only need one .deps.json file per console or web application, not per assembly. Class libraries in NuGet packages don’t need to bundle a deps.json file.